# How do I get the following output from this array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

This is the original array of objects:

```
const input = [

    {firstProperty: 'something', 
    money: 3, 
    user: 'john-smith'}, 
    {firstProperty: 'somethingDiff', 
    money: 7, 
    user: 'john-smith'}, 
    {firstProperty: 'somElse', 
    money: 14, 
    user: 'jane-doe'},
    {firstProperty: 'someOtherThing', 
    money: 2, 
    user: 'jane-doe'}]
```

And I would need to output the following:

```
const output = [
{user: 'john-smith',
totalMoney: 10},
{user: 'jane-doe',
totalMoney: 16}]
```

I have already achieved this result by using a bunch of for loops but I was looking for an elegant solution that uses only ES6 methods such as map, filter, reduce, etc.

Comment: Your input makes little sense.

Comment: This would make more sense if you change your input a bit (if possible of course). 
It would make more sense if the input was like this: `[ {firstProperty: "something, money: 3, user:"john smith""}, {firstProperty: "somethingelse", money: 4, user:"john smith""} ]`.

Copy and compare and you'll see what we mean

Comment: Looks like you edited Data Structure from original one. Updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the updated code it makes it even easier to get your result, my approach would still be to first aggregate and then map.

I updated the code per changes to your original post.

```js
const input = [
    {firstProperty: 'something', 
    money: 3, 
    user: 'john-smith'}, 
    {firstProperty: 'somethingDiff', 
    money: 7, 
    user: 'john-smith'}, 
    {firstProperty: 'somElse', 
    money: 14, 
    user: 'jane-doe'},
    {firstProperty: 'someOtherThing', 
    money: 2, 
    user: 'jane-doe'}
];

function sumByUser( input ) {
  // first aggregate the money per user
  const moneyByUser = input.reduce( (current, { user, money }) => {
    current[user] = (current[user] || 0) + money;
    return current;
  }, {} );
  
  // then create an array by using the keys for user names
  return Object
    .keys( moneyByUser )
    .map( user => ({ user, money: moneyByUser[user] }) );
}

console.log( sumByUser( input ) );
```

Comment: sorry, my input was wrong after all. I pasted the indexers without intention.

Comment: @nicokruk well, you only need to remove the object.values statement to make it work, so it would be easy yo adapt my current code to your needs

Comment: @nicokruk I updated the code, but as mentioned before this shouldn't have been a big deal as the principal still stands

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach of "Array.reduce" and "Array.from" as well

```js
var input = [{firstProperty: 'something', money: 3, user: 'john-smith'}, {firstProperty: 'somethingDiff', money: 7, user: 'john-smith'}, {firstProperty: 'somElse', money: 14, user: 'jane-doe'},{firstProperty: 'someOtherThing', money: 2, user: 'jane-doe'}]

var result = Array.from(input.reduce((m, { user, money }) => 
              m.set(user, { user, totalMoney: (m.get(user) && m.get(user).totalMoney || 0) + money })
            , new Map)
        , ([ _, d ]) => d)
       
       
       
console.log(result)
```